# If $f(a)=0$, $f^{(n)}(a)$ exists, then $F(x)=[f(x)]^n$ satisfies $F^{(k)}(a)=0,k=0,1,\cdots,n-1$.

Tags: calculus, differential

If $f(a)=0$, $f^{(n)}(a)$ exists, then $F(x)=[f(x)]^n$ satisfies $F^{(k)}(a)=0,k=0,1,\cdots,n-1$.

This is easy to verify.
But...

If $f^{(n)}(a)$ does not exist, could we find an example such that the conlcusion does not hold?

Comment: Take a non - differentiable function?

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe This is the case $n=1$, and $F^{(0)}(a)=F(a)=0$ holds naturally.